# run parallel process when another end in bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have a task when I have to run six python scripts from bash.
I have three short scripts (take a photo) and three long (image processing) that should run after photo is done.

I know that to make two process run in series I should write

```
python script1.py
python script2.py
```

and to make parallel execution I should write

```
python script1.py & python script2.py
```

But how can I achieve something like that:

[image]

2nd and 3rd process run parallel, after 1st,

4th and 5th run parallel when 2 is finished (3rd is still active)

6th run when 4th is finished (3rd and 5th is still active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `&` to a command to run it in the background, and use the `wait` builtin to wait for a background job to finish.

So a combination of those two things will do what you want if you run your scripts in the appropriate order, running the ones that don't have other processes depending on them to finish first in the background, and then waiting at the end for all the background ones to finish.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

demo() {
    echo "$1 starting for $2 seconds"
    sleep "$2"
    echo "$1 done"
}

echo "Begin Demonstration"

# Process 1 runs in the foreground.
demo 1 2
# Now run 3 in the background after 1 finishes.
demo 3 10 &
# And 2 in the foreground.
demo 2 2
# Now run 5 in the background after 2 finishes.
demo 5 10 &
# And 4 in the foreground.
demo 4 2
# Finally run 6 after 4 finishes.
demo 6 10
# Wait for any still running jobs to finish.
wait

echo "End Demonstration"
```

Running this script will output:

```
Begin Demonstration
1 starting for 2 seconds
1 done
2 starting for 2 seconds
3 starting for 10 seconds
2 done
4 starting for 2 seconds
5 starting for 10 seconds
4 done
6 starting for 10 seconds
3 done
5 done
6 done
End Demonstration
```

Comment: can you explain what means %+ after wait statement?

Comment: @alekq *In particular, `wait %+` will wait for the job most recently started in the background.* For details see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html

Comment: @alekq See edit for a simpler approach; I was over-complicating things.